# Is this Pharisee tradition that Jesus rebuked in the Talmud? Mark 7:9-13

Tags: second-temple-judaism

Mark 7:9-13, New King James:

> All too well you reject the commandment of God, that you may keep your tradition. For Moses said, ‘Honor your father and your mother’; and, ‘He who curses father or mother, let him be put to death.’ But you say, ‘If a man says to his father or mother, “Whatever profit you might have received from me is Corban”—’ (that is, a gift to God), then you no longer let him do anything for his father or his mother, making the word of God of no effect through your tradition which you have handed down. And many such things you do.

Here Jesus appears to be citing a specific [*halakha*](https://www.jewfaq.org/jewish_law) of the Pharisees, where they excuse a man from financially providing for his needful (ie elderly or ailing) parents in order to give it (*qorban*) at the Temple.

What Jesus referred to as the "traditions" were orally transmitted by the Pharisees at the time but would be committed to writing after the bar Kochva revolt as the [*Mishnah*](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Mishnah) or "oral law" as part of the [Jerusalem Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Yerushalmi) and the [Babylonian Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud).

While [English translations of the Mishnah are available](https://www.chabad.org/torah-texts/5689767/Mishnah), I have failed to find anything that looks like a match to what Jesus referenced in this passage.  **Was this *halakha* included in the Talmud?**  Or discussed in any other extra-Biblical source?

Comment: I posted the same answer here which is about Konam and Korban being same. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/73666/how-is-moses-and-jesus-contradictory-teaching-regarding-oaths-reconciled/83746#83746

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact match, but the Mishnah (the oldest portion of the Talmud) does address the something close to this: whether shame incurred by one's parents can form the basis for a vow to be dissolved. It is found among the many Talmudic discussions on *nedarim* (vows):

Mishnah Nedarim 9:1

> Rabbi Eliezer says: When halakhic authorities are approached with
> regard to the dissolution of a vow, they may broach dissolution with a
> person who took a vow by raising the issue of how taking the vow
> ultimately degraded the honor of his father and mother, asking him the following: 'Had you known that your parents would experience public shame due to your lax attitude toward your vow, would you still have taken the vow?' But the (other) Rabbis disagree with Rabbi Eliezer and prohibit broaching dissolution of a vow with this particular question.

The question Jesus addresses is more direct: whether one's vow to God takes precedence over the duty to one's parents. Jesus held to the more humanistic interpretation of the Law in this case. The particular Pharisees whom he argued against held that one's duty to God is paramount regardless of how the parents are affected. Ironically the Pharisees' position here has something in common with Jesus' own saying:

Matthew 10:37

> He who loves father and mother more than me is not worthy of me.

**Conclusion**: Mishnah Nedarim shows that there were disagreements among the rabbis about the question of when and how a vow may be dissolved. In that sense, Jesus was engaged in a *halakhic* debate consistent with rabbinic tradition. As [Lawrence M. Wills](https://www.thetorah.com/author/lawrence-m-wills) notes in the *Jewish Annotated New Testament*: "Rabbinic tradition... allowed release from *korban* when it deprived the parents of their due."

Comment: Could Mishnah Nedarim 2:4 be a match?  It seems to say vows are valid when based on anything that is sacrificed on the altar, or used to buy such sacrifice.  So if a man takes a vow to give as *korban* the money he would have used to support his aging parents, Mishnah Nedarim 2:4 would seem to affirm this vow and hold the man to his word.  Whereas Jesus seems to teach that the failure to provide for his needful parents renders the vow invalid because one cannot base a vow on an unclean gift.  Does that fit?

Comment: @wberry... sorry I didn't see your comment until now. Again, not an exact match but it does show that there was wiggle room, at least for some rabbis. One thing to keep in mind here is that the NT often treats "the Pharisees" as hold one opinion opposed to Jesus. In reality they held many opinions, and some would have agreed with him.

Answer (score 0):

The corrupt Churches/believers have always developed cunning ways to overrule and bypass the commandments of God. If a man gives the [benefits](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5772-chayeisarah/) for his parents as offering (to God) as a vow or oath, then he is freed or forbidden from all obligation towards the parents due to the vow. The similar cunning ways continued among sinners to bypass the law of God, even in the new covenant churches in the name of false grace and tradition.

We read in the Nedarim many such provisions for vows that forbid others any benefit through the vows, and we can assume that various versions of such vows were allowed by the Pharisees.

> [Mishnah Nedarim](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.9?lang=en) commentary 8.7 [....] And, so too, in the case of one who says to another: Benefiting from me is konam for you, i.e., you are prohibited from deriving benefit from me, if you do not come and give my son one kor of wheat and two barrels of wine, Rabbi Meir says: It is prohibited for the other individual to benefit from the speaker until he gives the gifts to his son.[...]
> Mishnah Nedarim 9.1
> Rabbi Eliezer says: When halakhic authorities are approached with regard to the dissolution of a vow, they may broach dissolution with a person who took a vow by raising the issue of how taking the vow ultimately degraded the honor of his father and mother, asking him the following: Had you known that your parents would experience public shame due to your lax attitude toward your vow, would you still have taken the vow? But the Rabbis disagree with Rabbi Eliezer and prohibit broaching dissolution of a vow with this particular question. To support the opinion of the Rabbis, Rabbi Tzadok said: Instead of broaching dissolution with him by raising the issue of the honor of his father and mother, let them broach dissolution with him by raising the issue of the honor of the Omnipresent. They should point out that a vow taken in the name of God lessens the honor of God, so they could ask him: If you had known that your vow would diminish the honor of God, would you have taken your vow? And if so, if this is a valid method of broaching dissolution, there are no vows. Nevertheless, the Rabbis concede to Rabbi Eliezer with regard to a vow concerning a matter that is between him and his father and mother, that they may broach dissolution with him by raising the issue of the honor of his father and mother, as in this case the extenuation is connected to this particular vow.

[Korban and Konam](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=konam%20korban&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) are words used in interchangeably as substitute words.

> Ramban on Numbers 30:3:1
> “[This means if] a person says: ‘May there be konam13The word konam is a substitute for korban , and is used for a vow of abstinence, meaning, “May this object be forbidden to me in the same way as it...disappears. for the Rabbis have said19Nedarim 2b. that in the case of vows one makes the [actual] object [referred to in the vow] forbidden to oneself [as when one says: “May this bread be konam13The word konam...is a substitute for korban , and is used for a vow of abstinence, meaning, “May this object be forbidden to me in the same way as it is forbidden to have any benefit from a holy offering.” upon me”],
> Commentary on the Torah by Ramban (Nachmanides). Translated and annotated by Charles B. Chavel. New York, Shilo Pub. House, 1971-1976

> English Explanation of Mishnah Nedarim 1:2:2
> One who says, “konam” “qonah” or “qonas”: these are the substitutes for korban. The normal substitute for “korban”, a sacrifice is “konam”. Our mishnah lists substitutes for “konam”.
> Mishnah Yomit by Dr. Joshua Kulp

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this matches what Jesus was teaching.  Maybe I'm confused over this remark from the Kulp commentary in Nedarim 2:2.  "All of the above formulas are valid if the word 'shevuah' or oath is used instead of a vow."  Does *korban* specifically refer to a Nazirite vow then?  Are there other types of vows?  What is the difference exactly between a vow and an oath?

Comment: Search on Judaism SE for terms difference. Korban means sacrifice, Konam is a similar thing. The relation is indirect to the ref of Jesus. *one who says to another: Benefiting from me is konam for you, i.e., you are prohibited from deriving benefit from me*: this means you can Konam cancel your obligation to parents as well. It's not hard to imagine such vows existed as well in light of this ref.